# The App Engine service account does not exist for "my-project"?

Tags: google-app-engine, deployment, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

I download google official latest python app engine demo and deploy with flex env, but this problem arises

```
size: 3458
DONE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) FAILED_PRECONDITION: The App Engine service account does not exist for "my-project".
```

And I checked the IAM service-xxxxxxxxx@gae-api-prod.google.com.iam.gserviceaccount.com already exists.
Someone can help me, please?

---

Solution:
Someone delete default app engine account, just add it and it solved.

Comment: Experienced the same problem...but resolved restoring the default deleted service account. This article will guide https://medium.com/@ajanthan/have-you-lost-your-appengine-default-service-account-and-the-world-went-dark-f4282dc0c434

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's either a wrong initialization or a wrong update of the service account.

Go to the API Lenny in the console, search for appengine disable and enable again the API. It should fix the problem.

If not, try the same process but delete the appengine flex service account before `service-<project number>@gae-api-prod.google.com.iam.gserviceaccount.com`

If it still doesn't work, delete also the default service in appengine component.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried but it failed again with the same issue.

Comment: Strange. Do you have a billing account on your project?

Comment: We have and we can deploy with GKE, GCF, and others.

Comment: Not sure that is related, but do you have already deploy a default appengine service?

Comment: I tried just now and I can deploy in standard env but can't deploy in flexible env and I also disabled and enable the flex API service.

Comment: Do you tried to delete the service account of appengine flex, then disable and enable  API?

Comment: No more idea. Sorry. Open a ticket to the [support](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers)

Comment: Thanks and I find out that someone deletes app engine default service account, and I added again then it works.

Comment: Can you do an edit to you answer to explain what happened (The fact that the service account was deleted)?